# Recover style of \section modified by titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

After the `\section` style is modified by the `titlesec` package, I want to return to the original style by `\let` and `\renewcommand`, but fails. Why and how to achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\section{Original Section Style}
\let\oldsection\section %store the original macro \section
\oldsection{Original Section Style stored}
\titleformat{\section}{\huge\color{red}}{\Roman{section}}{1em}{}
\section{New Section Style}
\let\section\oldsection % recovery of \section
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% I tried by another way
\section{I want to restore the original section style, but fails}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Different section styles may confuse readers however, as it breaks the coporate design somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In section 9.2 of the `titlesec` manual, you find that the default style for `\section` is

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Thus you can go back and forward:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}

\newcommand{\originalsections}{%
  \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}%
}
\newcommand{\modifiedsections}{%
  \titleformat{\section}{\huge\color{red}}{\Roman{section}}{1em}{}%
}

\originalsections

\begin{document}

\section{Original Section Style A}
\section{Original Section Style B}

\modifiedsections

\section{New Section Style A}
\section{New Section Style B}

\originalsections

\section{Original Section Style C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The old definition of `\section` etc. must be captured by a `\let` statement

**before**

`titlesec` changes `\section` etc, i.e.

```
\let\oldsection\section
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

[image]

Here is the modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldsection\section %store the original macro \section

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\section{Original Section Style}
\oldsection{Original Section Style stored}
\titleformat{\section}{\huge\color{red}}{\Roman{section}}{1em}{}
\section{New Section Style}
\let\section\oldsection % recovery of \section
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% I tried by another way
\section{I want to restore the original section style, but fails}
\end{document}
```